# Strange error doveadm

Tags: ubuntu, email, dovecot

I try to move mail from one user to another:

`sudo doveadm move -u touser INBOX user fromuser mailbox INBOX ALL`

In finally I get an error:

`doveadm(touser): Fatal: setresgid(1005(fromuser),1005(fromuser),8(mail)) failed with euid=1000(touser): Operation not permitted`

What does that error mean and how to fix it?

Comment: You need a root permissions (via `sudo`) to manipulate files ownership.

Comment: @Kondybas I have done it, I get error anyway.